Modify the width of each digit (0, 1, ..., 9) of a TTF font
We have designed an interface with the Montserrat font, but for many numeric displays (think of a calculator display), the fact that the digits don't have the same letter width and don't align vertically is a problem:

I have thought about using another font (e.g. monospace) specifically for digits, but the result is not optimal, because it does not match with the rest of the interface.
Question: what's the simplest way to edit the OpenSans-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf file, set all digit glyphs (0, 1, ..., 9) to the same width, and save into a new TTF output file?
If possible, would it be possible with a command-line tool and no GUI editor? so that we can do this automatically via a script in our build operations.

You're right @Luciano, but now everything has been designed with that font, which is very good for the rest of the project, so it's not possible to change it ;) I was curious if modifying the font digit glyphs can be easily done ;)

sorry, i deleted my previous comment once I saw it was possible to just change font settings externally :)

Montserrat has a tabular lining (monospaced numerals) option in its OpenType preferences. How to access these properties will depend on what platform / software you're using the font.
Since it looks like you're using it in a web project you could just set it with the  font-variant-numeric CSS property:
font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;

You litterally saved me 10 more hours of unsuccessful attempts. Thanks a lot! You can also add this answer here, I'll also accept it.

Must feel good to give such a simple yet extremely useful answer!

@Wolff it actually feels nice :)
